# The cons of accessing `arguments` object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arguments

The document of [PooledClass.js](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/shared/utils/PooledClass.js) from the React project says:

> A completely generic pooler is easy to implement, but would require accessing the `arguments` object.

So what are the cons of accessing the `arguments` object?

Comment: The answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13299529/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-access-the-arguments-object-to-every-function-that-takes) explain some of the problems in accessing it. In short: it's slower and it's better to have named arguments when possible. More information can also be found [here (specific to V8).](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers#3-managing-arguments)

Comment: I must admit that I wasn't considerate enough to ask this question. Another close vote.